# How to enable the option open and save in prompt window of Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I've recently upgrade to Internet Explorer 11 and now when I try to download/open a .PDF file from the internet I get the following options in IE. The Save and Open option is disabled/greyed out.

As shown below

[image]

I couldn't find the question similar to this or I was not able to search properly.

Answer (score 2):

Since i have not found any answer i tried doing below

In order to do these changes we must have admin permisson 
below are the to be steps performed
Problem : sometime when we download a file the open option is disabled :
 [image: save and open option disabled]

Steps to enable:
**Tools->internet options ->advanced tab ->security options->uncheck as shown in below snip->apply->click ok** 
below is the option to be unchecked 
[image]

After this settings we will be able to see below options 
[image]

Comment: If someone has found better answer please guide me through this issue